# ID value in mySQL is auto_increment but seems generated in netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, sql, netbeans

I'm fairly new to developing web apps in Java. I just connected the database, and as seen in the pictures, my ID_patient is auto_increment, but in Netbeans it looks generated.

```
INSERT INTO sys.patient values('5','elif','nil','er','elif@hotmail.com','11111111111','1234a','istanbul')
```

The new record inserted wants this value, while i want it to take

```
INSERT INTO sys.patient values('elif','nil','er','elif@hotmail.com','11111111111','1234a','istanbul')
```

and auto-increment and give the id as 1,2,3,4...etc.

how can I fix this?
thank you

[in netbeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/06ghB.png)

[in mysql](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LCuKl.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to create an insert query where you don't want to provide an id and the database should generate it automatically based on table defination then you need to create insert query where you have to mention columns names.
Example

```
INSERT INTO <TABLENAME>(COLUMN1, COLUMN2, COLUMN3, COLUMN4) 
VALUES
(VALUE1,VALUE2, VALUE 3,VALUE 4);
```

So in ur case it should be

```
INSERT INTO PATIENT(FirstName,MiddleName,LastName,E_mail)
values
('myname','mymiddlename','mylastname','myemailid');
```

Sequence of column names and their values are very important. They should match exactly. If you don't provide a value for one of column and if its is auto increment, then DB will add an value to it else it will add null value.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still gives error; Error code 1136, SQL state 21S01: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
Line 2, column 1

Comment: Make sure you give the same number of columns in your insert and in your value. Maybe show us the query you are trying to execute so we can try to find the issue